# Converting mysql_query to mysqli_query

Tags: mysqli

I just moved to xampp version 7.0.13, which now has PHP 7.x, and the following query no longer works. I was Hoping someone can help me convert the following to mysqli query. I don't write code, so any help you could give me would be great.

// Count the number of rows in the member table
   $rows = "SELECT * FROM `$db_name`.`$tbl_name`";
   $count_rows = mysql_query( $rows );

Comment: use PHP PDO with prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

here is your example with PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM :table';
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$count = $statement->execute(array('table' => 'your-table-name'))->rowCount();
```